# Why this code is giiving different result in Python and Pypy3?

Tags: python-3.x, hash, tuples, pypy

Given an integer, n, and n space-separated integers as input, create a tuple, t, of those n integers. Then compute and print the result of hash(t).

In Python 3 this gives the different output compare to Pypy3. So why the same logic is giving two different result?

```
n = int(input())
print(hash(tuple(map(int, input().split()))))
```

My output:

```
-3550055125485641917
```

Expected output:

```
3713081631934410656
```

Comment: Aside from the correct answer by jurez, pypy makes a reasonable attempt at getting the same hash values as cpython for the simple types.  I'm getting the same results when I tried tuples of integers.  Please provide a way to reproduce?  We need the exact versions, and the OS, and the actual tuple that is used.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: your assumption that `hash()` values should be the same is wrong.

`hash()` values are used for hashing, e.g. [when you put something as a key in a dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

Hashing is implementation specific, and the value of a hash function has no meaning for the user. The only guarantee is that within the same Python running process, two equal objects should have the same hash value. The value *might* be different not only between different Python versions, but also with the same Python version if you run the program many times, or with different Python implementation, or with different CPU architecture, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because Pypy3 uses the algorithm `siphash24` while python3 uses `siphash13`. You can see the difference using:

```
import sys
print(sys.hash_info)
```

For example, in my system, for Pypy3 the value is:

```
(width=64, modulus=2305843009213693951, inf=314159, nan=0, imag=1000003, algorithm='siphash24', hash_bits=64, seed_bits=128, cutoff=0)
```

and for python3:

```
(width=64, modulus=2305843009213693951, inf=314159, nan=0, imag=1000003, algorithm='siphash13', hash_bits=64, seed_bits=128, cutoff=0)
```